# When is an NTFS ReparsePoint not a ReparsePoint?

Tags: winapi, backup, ntfs, computer-forensics

While testing backup and restore software, I have encountered the following anomalous circumstance: after running a comprehensive inventory of files and folders, I've got some files that claim to be `Archive | Sparse | ReparsePoint`. After restoring, these files are only `Archive | Sparse`.

In the inventory, I produce a series of SHA1 hashes of the `BackupRead` streams, and these hashes match both before and after restoration...meaning, I put back what I originally read. Yet, if there had been a `ReparseData` block, and I failed to write it out, the hashes would not have matched.

In other files that have this set of attributes restoration occurs normally and have all the expected attributes restored. That means to be that `ReparseData` was encountered, and the resulting file shows as a `ReparsePoint` post-restore.

After restoration, the operating system appears to act normally, the files load and execute (many of these weird files are .DLLs).

I've no problems with permissions - I've asserted all the necessary privileges, and I open the files with the `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` in preparation for `BackupWrite`. Everything *appears* to work correctly.

But I'm worried. I don't know how or why I lost the ReparsePoint flag. I don't know how it got marked as a ReparsePoint in the first place. I don't know if this is some weird artifact of the original installation. Is there some way to set the `ReparsePoint` attribute w/o actually having a reparse point in the file?

Here's a short list of some of the affected files and locations:

```
Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-filehistory-core_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_e2812d3f8d830dbb 
  (all files)
Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-gdi_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.0_none_d74783f3713901b3
  atmfd.dll
  atmlib.dll
  dciman32.dll
```

Most (but not all) of the offending files also happen to be hard-linked in other locations on the volume (typically way down in `Program Files`). HardLinks are definitely not reparse points (they're implemented differently).

There are several hundred of these (in total). The entire volume has about 160K files. Should I just get over it?

Comment: Depending on your context, one possible explanation for the files being reparse points originally  is deduplication.  Tiered storage might also use reparse points - at any rate, Remote Storage did back in Server 2003, though I'm not sure whether Storage Spaces does.  At any rate, it sounds to me as though the system is removing the reparse point as soon as you open the file, does the source file still have the ReparsePoint flag after backing it up?

Comment: "I open the files with the FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT in preparation for BackupWrite." - you must do this in preparation BackupRead, but not BackupWrite (or you confused in text). "many of these weird files are .DLLs" - so you have 0 byte size x.dll which point to y.dll ? and what is reparse tag ? IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK ? IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT worked only with folders

Comment: @RbMm, so far, I've not had a reason to open/know the reparse flags...and hoping that stays true. You think there's reason I need to know? I use FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_FLAG in both read and write.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, should have mentioned - the test image is a win 7 pro that's been upgraded to win 10 pro...would be surprised to find de-dup there. After restore, the ReparsePoint flag is just gone :-| That's the mystery. BTW - thousands of hard-links into \windows.old (surprise)

Comment: My question was whether the ReparsePoint flag is still present or not on the *original* file after you perform the backup, i.e., before you perform the restore.  What sort of imaging technology are you using to install the test machine?  Perhaps that's responsible for the reparse points - come to think of it, even a standard Windows install from MS media uses imaging (based on the WIM format) which includes some sort of deduplication, though I didn't think it was reparse point based.

Comment: (My best guess, though, would be that MS have started doing something clever with reparse points as part of servicing, to reduce the amount of disk space used by the WinSxS folder.)

Comment: "I've not had a reason to open/know the reparse flags." - but you have reason understand situation ? i be select one such file and test(and post full info) for this case - this is file or folder ? full name. SubstituteName, and PrintName, ReparseTag. before BackupRead and after BackupWrite

Comment: The flag is still present in in the *original* files post-backup. The backup stream is shipped off and shredded so I can't make any claims about what the backup *looks like*. The strange state came to be that way after running the retail free upgrade from win 7 to 10. I'd wondered if it was some cheeky way to mark some files during that upgrade process...or a spurious artifact. Indeed - winsxs is hardlink city - a suspicious location for sure. Also wondered if the flag was the result of having been copied from a mounted .wim.

Comment: @RbMm, in NTFS, hard links aren't implemented with reparse tags. They're just multiple directory entries pointing to the same file.

Comment: @Clay - i don`t understand - are you have problems with reparse points or hard links. of course this is different things

Comment: Yes - it's most unusual. They're hard-linked .dlls (mostly) that happen to have the ReparsePoint flag in their attributes - but no Reparse tag in the files.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - almost certain that files moved from a SIS-enabled volume onto distribution media end up producing artifacts like these. They're both reparse-point based and sparse. Hmmmm....